# invert rows and cols SQLite

Tags: ios, core-data, sqlite

I'm developing and iOS game and I want to switch cols and rows

For example here is the stat's table :

```
StatName (STRING) | StatValue (NUMBER)
--------------------------------------
NbJoker           |      12
--------------------------------------
NbPlayed          |      71
--------------------------------------
NbPause           |      87
--------------------------------------
```

I need

```
NbJoker | NbPlayed | NbPause
----------------------------
12      |     71   | 87
```

Is that possible ?
Thanks!

Comment: I think you'll need to add a little more detail about what you're trying to accomplish. Do you wish to display the information with the rows/columns switched? Or do you want to change the data structure in the database? If the latter, what entity do the new rows correspond to?

Comment: thanks, Rajaganesh has just answered, it is exactly what I needed !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I do not know SQL Lite. But If the below syntax works.

It's like the same as a Transpose in any SQL.

```
SELECT SUM(T1) AS NBJOKER, SUM(T2) AS NBPLAYED, SUM(T3) AS NBPAUSE FROM (
SELECT STATVALUE AS T1,O AS T2,0 AS T3 FROM TABLE_X WHERE STATNAME='NBJOKER'
UNION ALL
SELECT 0, STATVALUE, 0 FROM TABLE_X WHERE STATNAME='NBLAYED'
UNION ALL
SELECT 0, 0, STATVALUE FROM TABLE_X WHERE STATNAME='NBPAUSE'
)
```